# On a Surjection

Tags: set-theory

For any set $B$ let $\mathcal{P}(B)$ denote the set of all subsets of $B$.

Let $A$ be an infinite set and suppose there exists a surjection $f : A \mapsto \mathcal{P}(A)\setminus A$. Consider the set $D := \{a : a \in A\ \textrm{but}\ a \notin f(a)\}$. Is it ever possible that the set $A\setminus D$ is empty?

Comment: Anything’s possible if you have a surjection $f:A\to\wp(A)\setminus A$: a false statement implies **every** statement!

Comment: @Brian: The statement isn't false; it just severely restricts the possible sets $A$.

Comment: @joriki: Uhh, it is false. Cantor's theorem shows that if $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ then it is not surjective. Note that $\mathcal P(A)$ has the same size as $\mathcal P(A)\setminus A$ (even if you parse this as removing all singletons).

Comment: @Asaf, Brian: Sorry, I somehow missed the "infinite" part :-)

Comment: Even without choice, one can prove that if $A$ is infinite and $n\in\mathbb N$, then the union of $n$ disjoint copies of $A$ is strictly smaller than $\mathcal P(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no such surjection, the set $D$ is a set which is not in the range of $f$. That is its purpose. It is possible that $D=A$, it is possible that it is empty as well.

For example let $A=\mathbb N$ and consider the map $f(n)=\{k\mid k>n\}$. Clearly $n\notin f(n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Souvik: First you need to better define what do you mean $\mathcal P(A)\setminus A$.

Comment: The relative complement of B in A (also called the set-theoretic difference of A and B), denoted by A\B      (or A − B), is the set of all elements which are members of A but not members of B,that's what I wanted to mean.I actually asked the question to be able to show by contradiction that such a surjection in fact does not exist,for that I needed that A\D be never empty.It would be really helpful if you plese give some account of the proof that no surjection from A to P(A)\A exists.

Comment: @Souvik: It would be helpful if you explain what you mean by writing $\mathcal P(A)\setminus A$ mean. I know what is set difference, and I know that $A\neq\{A\}$ in general. I also know that $A$ doesn't have to be a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$ in general. So what do you mean when you write that expression?

Comment: The expression is still properly defined. For example, $\emptyset$ might be an element of $A$ and hence is to be removd from $\mathcal P(A)$. For typical sets (e.g. with its elements considerd as urelements), $\mathcal P(A)$ and $A$ are of course disjoint. Or consider ordinals: Their elements are also subsets hence it might make sense to talk of $\mathcal P(A)\setminus A$.

Comment: @Hagen: Yes. It is well defined and whatnot. But often people write $A$ and they mean $\{A\}$. Yes, it is possible for $A\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$. But it is also possible that $A\cap\mathcal P(A)=\varnothing$. Since this is quite case dependent it seems to me that it is likely the OP means **something else**.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Agreed, but it seems to me that the OP has stated  in his comment above that he really meant what he wrote. Of course it never hurts to clarify.

Comment: @Souvik: There is always a simple solution, replace $A$ by $A'$ such that $|A|=|A'|$ and $A'\cap\mathcal P(A')=\varnothing$. Now the proof goes exactly as Cantor's theorem. Also note that the proof of Cantor's theorem is **not** by contradiction, you don't assume the existence of a surjection, you simply *construct* the set which is not in the image.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry for the inconvenience , I actually meant {A} when I wrote A so that {A}⊆P(A) and I do know a proof of Cantor's theorem by contradiction.

Comment: @Souvik: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hagen: See Souvik's last comment.

Comment: @Asaf: proof of Cantor's Theorem:- Suppose that f : A ---> P(A) is a surjection.Since f(a) is a subset of A , either a belongs to f(a) or it does not. We let D:={a belongs to A : a does not belong to f(a) } . Since D is a subset of A, if f is a surjection , then D =f(m) for some m belonging to A. We must have either m is in D or m is not in D . If m is in D , then since D =f(m),we must have , m is in f(m) , contrary to the definition of D. Similarly,if m is not in D , then m is not in f(m) , so that by definition m is in D , which is also a contradiction .

Comment: @Asaf: Therefore, f can not be a surjection and since f was arbitary(general) mapping of A onto P(A) , there is no surjection of A onto P(A) ,this proves the Theorem of Cantor by contradiction.

Comment: @Souvik: Yes. This is the proof of Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @Asaf: Um,so why did you say it is not  by contradiction?

Comment: @Souvik: Because you don't *have* to assume by contradiction. You could also do the following: Assume $f\colon A\to\mathcal P(A)$ is a function. Let $D=\{a\in A\mid a\notin f(a)\}$. Now $D$ is not in the range of $f$ as the usual argument goes, therefore $f$ is not surjective. We *constructed* a counterexample, we didn't have to assume by contradiction here.

Comment: @Asaf: Yeah right , that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in ZFC such a surjection cannot exist, because $|P(A)|>|A|$, and if $|A|\ge\aleph_0$ (that is, $A$ is infinite), then $|P(A)\setminus A| = |P(A)|$ still $>|A|$. (however you mean $P(A)\setminus A$ - probably via the canonical embedding $a\mapsto\{a\}$).
Whilst, if there is a surjection $A\to B$, then $|A|\ge|B|$.

On the other hand, there are set theories, e.g. [Quine's New Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations), where Russell's paradox is resolved not by the *bigness* of the sets, and there there exists the *set of everything*, say $\Omega$, and there $P(\Omega)$ is *contained* in $\Omega$. Well, $A=\Omega$ is still not a good choice because $P(A)\setminus A=\emptyset$, but it may make some sense what you ask...